# Remove duplicate values from the result of MongoDB objects

Tags: java, mongodb

How to remove duplicate values from the result of MongoDB objects?

I have some records in my mongodb as follows

```
{"Filename":"PHP Book.pdf","Author":"John" ,"Description":"This is my PHP Book"} 
{"Filename":"Java Book.html" ,"Author":"Paul" ,"Description":"This is my JAVA Book"}
{"Filename":".NET Book.doc" ,"Author":"James" ,"Description":"This is my .NET Book"}
```

below is my code to search Filename and Description fields which contains "Java" word and displaying their filenames.

```
Mongo m = new Mongo("10.0.0.26", 27017) ;
DB db = m.getDB("soft") ;
DBCollection col = db.getCollection("poc") ;

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject query1 = new BasicDBObject();

String KeyWord="JAVA";
query.put("Filename",  java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(KeyWord));
query1.put("Content",  java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(KeyWord));
DBCursor cursor = col.find(query) ;
DBCursor cursor1 = col.find(query1) ;
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject o = cursor.next();
        System.out.println("File name contains JAVA:"+o.get("Filename"));
        }
    while (cursor1.hasNext()) {
        DBObject ob = cursor1.next();
        System.out.println("File name whose content contains JAVA:"+ob.get("Filename"));
            }
```

I am getting the following output:

```
File Name Contains JAVA:Java Book.html
File Name  whose content Contains JAVA:Java Book.html
```

I am getting same file name from both filename and content queries.I want to remove the duplicate values.Please suggest me.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried something like: `new BasicDBObject("Filename", new BasicDBObject("$ne", ...).append("Content", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(KeyWord));`

Comment: what should i give after $ne in above command

Comment: I was thinking you would give it the same regex you are giving to the `Filename` query. That way the `Content` query would exclude results from the `Filename` query.

Comment: What constitutes a duplicate value here? In your example, you're not considering the `_id` of the documents returned by the query. Also, what does it mean to "remove the duplicate values"? If a single document has "JAVA" in both of its `Filename` and `Content` fields, do you intend to delete that document?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a $or query, something like:

```
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start().or(
    new BasicDBObject("Filename",  java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(KeyWord)),
    new BasicDBObject("Content", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(KeyWord))).get();
```

and do it as a single query instead of two separate queries.

Please be advised that MongoDB will not be able to use an index for non-anchored regular expressions.  See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/ for details.